# qml JSON recursively parse non flat Json result set

Tags: javascript, json, qt, qml

I am consuming a simple Web API with `XMLHttpRequest` using this QML code, the API responds with a JSON result set.

```
Page1 {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        getInformation(xyz)
    }
    function getInformation(xyz) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest;
        var httpString = "https://api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup?upc="
        httpString += xyz
        req.open("GET", httpString);
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            var status = req.readyState;
            if (status === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                var objectArray = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                if (objectArray.errors !== undefined)
                    console.log("Error fetching barcode: " + objectArray.errors[0].message)
                else {
                    for (var key in objectArray) {
                        var jsonObject = objectArray[key];
                        console.log("thekey:" , key)
                        console.log("the Object:", jsonObject)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        req.send();

        }
}
```

The code is fine and I am getting a result all the time, but the result looks like this:

```
thekey: code
the Object: OK
thekey: total
the Object: 1
thekey: offset
the Object: 0
thekey: items
the Object: [[object Object]]
```

and I want to get the details of the last object `the Object: [[object Object]]` which I know is another `key/value` pair JSON set .. I found similar posts addressing the issue with `ajax` but I don't know nor I am using `ajax`, **I am seeking options to convert last object into another array** in my QML code?

Comment: The problem is not in the parsing, `JSON.parse()` should work fine, the problem is that qt doesn't properly display js objects in the console and that you are not recursively iterating.

Comment: @dtech, yes certainly I knew the parsing worked, but I didn't know how to _recursively_ iterate a json result set. I will try p-a-o-l-o function, I think I should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a function to dump a json object and use it recursively:

```
function dumpJSONObject(jsonObject, indent) {

     var ind = new Array(indent * 2).join( ' ' );

     for (var key in jsonObject) {

         if(typeof(jsonObject[key]) == 'object') {

             console.log( ind + key + ": ");
             dumpJSONObject(jsonObject[key], indent + 1);

         } else {             

             console.log( ind + key + ": " + jsonObject[key]);
         }
     }
}
```

In your function:

```
function getInformation() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest;
    var httpString = "https://api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup?upc="
    httpString += "042100005264"
    req.open("GET", httpString);
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var status = req.readyState;
        if (status === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            var objectArray = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
            if (objectArray.errors !== undefined)
                console.log("Error fetching barcode: " + objectArray.errors[0].message)
            else {

                dumpJSONObject( objectArray, 0 ); //here

            }
        }
    }

    req.send();
 }
```

The output for upc code 042100005264 is like this:

```
qml: code: OK
qml: total: 1
qml: offset: 0
qml: items: 
qml:  0: 
qml:    ean: 0042100005264
qml:    title: Dewalt Bostitch 12 Volt 12v Max Lithium Ion Cordless Battery Pack
qml:    description: 
qml:    upc: 042100005264
qml:    elid: 391768274284
qml:    brand: Soft Surroundings
qml:    model: 
qml:    color: Black
qml:    size: 
qml:    dimension: 
qml:    weight: 
qml:    lowest_recorded_price: 4.99
qml:    highest_recorded_price: 95
qml:    images: 
qml:    offers:
```

Comment: what is "indent" and "ind" .. arbitrary vars?

Comment: `indent` is an integer that get incremented at each recursion, `ind` is a string of `indent * 2` spaces put at the beginning of each line. You can get rid of them entirely if you don't care about indentation. By the way, I edited the function to show the objects key.

Comment: Yes I am getting it as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Within the for loop have you tried checking jsonObject type? From this you can then print out inner node data..

Something like..

```
if (typeof(jsonObject) === "object") {
    var innerObject = jsonObject;
    for (var innerkey in innerObject ) {
        //Do stuff..
    }
}
```